# Need Image scratch animation runs automatically

Tags: javascript, image, scratchcard

I have seen many image scratch examples, which work on touchmove event, I need same scratch effect runs automatically in javascript. and is it possbile to paint the image in same way automatically?

I don't have idea any how to start it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: If you have `document.querySelector('someSelector').addEventListener('touchmove', someFunction);` change it to `someFunction();`

Comment: @mplungjan sharing the example https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yJQxLX , It doesn't work that way, it erases the portion wherever finger goes

Comment: Please click [edit], then click the button with the `[<>]` icon and make a [mcve] here as we have asked repeatedly